# Navigate a route without following it in the SKMapView

Tags: ios, skmaps

SKMaps is an excellent framework for a lot of mapping uses. I have a bit of a unique requirement and I'm hoping someone might have a solution. I'm curious if I can calculate a route, paint that route on the map, and then start navigation *without* having the map adopt the follow-the-driver UI. I want to be able to continue some basic interaction with the map (including animating different points to the center, etc) while navigation is in-progress.

My ViewController is both the routing delegate and the navigation delegate of the SKRoutingService shared instance. I did attempt to set the routing service's mapView pointer to nil when the route gets calculated, right before I start navigation, but to no success -- the mapView still zooms into the current location, the current position icon changes to the navigation one, and the map starts following the driver.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the following **after** starting navigation:

```
[[SKRoutingService sharedInstance]startNavigationWithSettings:navSettings];    
self.mapView.settings.followUserPosition = NO;
self.mapView.settings.headingMode = SKHeadingModeNone;
self.mapView.settings.displayMode = SKMapDisplayMode2D;
SKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.9667, 23.7167);
region.zoomLevel = 17;
self.mapView.visibleRegion = region;
```

This would start the navigation but not change the view (the user position will still change on the map, reflecting the change in position)

Comment: I'll try that. I'm inclined to believe that the followUserPosition property applies to the map view while not navigating, but I can try it anyway.

Comment: Still breaks into navigation mode. Essentially I only want the text/image of the turn-by-turn navigation, without it doing anything to the map view. This allows me more control over what's going on the map and how the user interacts with it.

Comment: Ok  - let us investigate and see how this is possible

Comment: That works! Thanks! Clearly there are some tweaks to iron out but by and large that does what I want it to do.